# Issues with mysql gem when i run bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to work for a project i m working on other devises. I just migrated the codes to my laptop and i need to run bundle install to have all gems installed.

The only one that could not go through is mysql. This is the message I get:

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

Then I ran sudo gem install mysql2 but I still ran into the same error: 
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

What is the best way to solve the conflict? Thanks!

Comment: please post your gem file.

Comment: it's very long but this section is the related one: # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'mysql2'
#https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set
gem 'awesome_nested_set', github: 'collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets

Comment: I ran brew install mysql, but still doesn't help

Comment: try to run this command `sudo gem install mysql — –with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config` if fails try this without sudo command

Comment: Try `bundle update`. If this doesn't work - Delete your Gemfile.lock and do `bundle install`. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: this comment passes but when i run bundle install again, same error happens.

Comment: Must be bundler issue, try `gem cleanup bundler` and then `gem install bundler`.

Comment: Please show the full output from the error.

Answer (score 0):

Following below steps

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
3. gem install mysql2